# How to use AWK to print associative array in a loop correctly?

Tags: arrays, string, awk, substring

```
Beth    45  0
Danny   33  0
Thomas  22  40  
Mark    65  100 
Mary    29  121 
Susie   39  76.5
Joey    51  189.52
Peter   23  78.26
Maximus 34  289.71
Rebecca 21  45.79
Sophie  26  28.44
Barbara 24  107.36
Elizabeth   35  105.69
Peach   40  102.69
Lily    41  123
```

The above is a data file which has three fields: name, age, salary.

I want to print average salary, number, and names for people aged above 30 and under 30.

In this exercise, I want to practise using strings as subscripts.

Here is my AWK code:

```
BEGIN { OFS = "\t\t" }   
{
    if ($2 < 30) 
    {   
        a = "age below 30";
        salary[a] += $NF; 
        count[a]++;
        name[a] = name[a] $1 "\t";
    }   
    else
    {   
        a = "age equals or above 30";
        salary[a] += $NF; 
        count[a]++;
        name[a] = name[a] $1 "\t";
    }   
}

END {
    for (a in salary)
        for (a in count)
            for (a in name)
            {
                print "The average salary of " a " is " salary[a] / count[a];
                print "There are " count[a] " people "  a ; 
                print "Their names are " name[a];
                print "********************************************************";
            }
}
```

The following is the output:

```
The average salary of age equals or above 30 is 109.679
There are 9 people age equals or above 30
Their names are Beth    Danny   Mark    Susie   Joey    Maximus Elizabeth   Peach   Lily    
********************************************************
The average salary of age below 30 is 70.1417
There are 6 people age below 30
Their names are Thomas  Mary    Peter   Rebecca Barbara Sophie  
********************************************************
The average salary of age equals or above 30 is 109.679
There are 9 people age equals or above 30
Their names are Beth    Danny   Mark    Susie   Joey    Maximus Elizabeth   Peach   Lily    
********************************************************
The average salary of age below 30 is 70.1417
There are 6 people age below 30
Their names are Thomas  Mary    Peter   Rebecca Barbara Sophie  
********************************************************
The average salary of age equals or above 30 is 109.679
There are 9 people age equals or above 30
Their names are Beth    Danny   Mark    Susie   Joey    Maximus Elizabeth   Peach   Lily    
********************************************************
The average salary of age below 30 is 70.1417
There are 6 people age below 30
Their names are Thomas  Mary    Peter   Rebecca Barbara Sophie  
********************************************************
The average salary of age equals or above 30 is 109.679
There are 9 people age equals or above 30
Their names are Beth    Danny   Mark    Susie   Joey    Maximus Elizabeth   Peach   Lily    
********************************************************
The average salary of age below 30 is 70.1417
There are 6 people age below 30
Their names are Thomas  Mary    Peter   Rebecca Barbara Sophie  
********************************************************
```

The output is very difficult for me to understand.

What I anticipated should look like this:

```
The average salary of age equals or above 30 is 109.679
There are 9 people age equals or above 30
Their names are Beth    Danny   Mark    Susie   Joey    Maximus Elizabeth   Peach   Lily    
********************************************************
The average salary of age equals or above 30 is 109.679
There are 9 people age equals or above 30
Their names are Thomas  Mary    Peter   Rebecca Barbara Sophie  
********************************************************
The average salary of age equals or above 30 is 109.679
There are 6 people age below 30
Their names are Beth    Danny   Mark    Susie   Joey    Maximus Elizabeth   Peach   Lily    
********************************************************
The average salary of age equals or above 30 is 109.679
There are 6 people age below 30
Their names are Thomas  Mary    Peter   Rebecca Barbara Sophie  
********************************************************
The average salary of age below 30 is 70.1417
There are 9 people age equals or above 30
Their names are Beth    Danny   Mark    Susie   Joey    Maximus Elizabeth   Peach   Lily    
********************************************************
The average salary of age below 30 is 70.1417
There are 9 people age equals or above 30
Their names are Thomas  Mary    Peter   Rebecca Barbara Sophie  
********************************************************
The average salary of age below 30 is 70.1417
There are 6 people age below 30
Their names are Beth    Danny   Mark    Susie   Joey    Maximus Elizabeth   Peach   Lily    
********************************************************
The average salary of age below 30 is 70.1417
There are 6 people age below 30
Their names are Thomas  Mary    Peter   Rebecca Barbara Sophie  
********************************************************
```

**So my first question is** :  Where did I understand wrong?

**And my second question is** : 
I actually don't need so many loops.  I just need

```
The average salary of age equals or above 30 is 109.679
There are 9 people age equals or above 30
Their names are Beth    Danny   Mark    Susie   Joey    Maximus Elizabeth   Peach   Lily    
********************************************************
The average salary of age equals or above 30 is 109.679
There are 9 people age equals or above 30
Their names are Thomas  Mary    Peter   Rebecca Barbara Sophie  
********************************************************
```

`for (a in salary, count, names)` doesn't work.  Is there a better way ?

Comment: What happens if you remove `for (a in salary) for (a in count)`?

Comment: Thanks, it works. I have also found for (a in salary) for (a in count) for (a in name) , whichever one of these three for() can solve the issue. Still a little weird to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (x in salary)
    for (y in count)
        for (z in name)
            print "foo"
```

says `for every index in salary, loop through every index in count and while doing so, for every index in count loop through every index in name and print "foo" each time`. So if salary, count, and name each had 3 entries then you'd print "foo" 3*3*3 = 9 times.

It gets more complicated than that in your code though because you're using the same variable to hold the index value of each array at every level of the nested loop:

```
for (a in salary)
    for (a in count)
        for (a in name)
```

so I'm not sure what awk is going to do with that - it may even be undefined behavior.

Since all 3 arrays have the same indices, just pick one of the arrays and loop on it's indices and then you can access all 3 arrays using that same index.

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    bracket = "age " ($2 < 30 ? "under" : "equals or above") " 30"

    names[bracket] = (bracket in names ? names[bracket] "\t" : "") $1
    count[bracket]++
    salary[bracket] += $NF
}
END {
    for (bracket in names) {
        print "The average salary of", bracket, "is", salary[bracket] / count[bracket]
        print "There are", count[bracket], "people",  bracket
        print "Their names are", names[bracket]
        print "********************************************************"
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
The average salary of age equals or above 30 is 109.679
There are 9 people age equals or above 30
Their names are Beth    Danny   Mark    Susie   Joey    Maximus Elizabeth       Peach   Lily
********************************************************
The average salary of age under 30 is 70.1417
There are 6 people age under 30
Their names are Thomas  Mary    Peter   Rebecca Sophie  Barbara
********************************************************
```